# Unexpected token (position:TEXT "@1:2 in java.io.InputStreamReader@3422132)

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and Android Studio and trying to parse XML that comes from .NET Web Services, The XML I am working looks like below

```
<RegisterViewModal>
  <RegList>
    <Register>
      <Availability>test</Availability>
      <Rating>0</Rating>
      <Citieslist>
        <Citieslist1>
          <Citieslist1>
            <Cityid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Cityid>
            <Countryid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Countryid>
            <Cityname>hyderabad</Cityname>
          </Citieslist1>
        </Citieslist1>
      </Citieslist>
      <CountryId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</CountryId>
      <IsQuote>false</IsQuote>
      <IsRegisterd>false</IsRegisterd>
    </Register>
  </RegList>
</RegisterViewModal>
```

I have tried to change the encoding to UTF-8, still issue stays.

```
String  Resultxml=  ServiceCallsLayer.TerstService();
String s1 = URLDecoder.decode(Resultxml, "UTF-8");
DocumentBuilder db=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s1.getBytes()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid xml has to start with an XML declaration, like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

If the result from your web service doesn't include it, it's not valid xml. But you could put it in front of your resultxml before you parse it.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for your answer i added above line to at start of my xml and the issue stays same, now it is showing Unexpected token (position:TEXT "@1:40 in java.io.InputStreamReader@7f18e83)

Comment: There was a single quote in the middle of xml which causing the error, Thanks for your time.